Java Spring Boot 3,x Upgrade results in SQS Error
As a part of upgrading Spring Boot 3.x, Spring Cloud 3.x, AWS SDK 2.x and Java 17, getting the below error related to SQS security token.
Caused by: software.amazon.awssdk.services.sqs.model.SqsException: The security token included in the request is invalid. (Service: Sqs, Status Code: 403, Request ID: 13c71e7e-67a3-5ade-a474-410b92f7b091)
at software.amazon.awssdk.services.sqs.model.SqsException$BuilderImpl.build(SqsException.java:104) ~[sqs-2.21.46.jar:na]
at software.amazon.awssdk.services.sqs.model.SqsException$BuilderImpl.build(SqsException.java:58) ~[sqs-2.21.46.jar:na]
at software.amazon.awssdk.protocols.json.internal.unmarshall.AwsJsonProtocolErrorUnmarshaller.unmarshall(AwsJsonProtocolErrorUnmarshaller.java:92) ~[aws-json-protocol-2.21.46.jar:na]
at software.amazon.awssdk.protocols.json.internal.unmarshall.AwsJsonProtocolErrorUnmarshaller.handle(AwsJsonProtocolErrorUnmarshaller.java:66) ~[aws-json-protocol-2.21.46.jar:na]
at software.amazon.awssdk.protocols.json.internal.unmarshall.AwsJsonProtocolErrorUnmarshaller.handle(AwsJsonProtocolErrorUnmarshaller.java:41) ~[aws-json-protocol-2.21.46.jar:na]
at software.amazon.awssdk.core.http.MetricCollectingHttpResponseHandler.lambda$handle$0(MetricCollectingHttpResponseHandler.java:52) ~[sdk-core-2.21.46.jar:na]
at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.util.MetricUtils.measureDurationUnsafe(MetricUtils.java:99) ~[sdk-core-2.21.46.jar:na]
at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.util.MetricUtils.measureDurationUnsafe(MetricUtils.java:92) ~[sdk-core-2.21.46.jar:na]
at software.amazon.awssdk.core.http.MetricCollectingHttpResponseHandler.handle(MetricCollectingHttpResponseHandler.java:52) ~[sdk-core-2.21.46.jar:na]
at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.async.AsyncResponseHandler.lambda$prepare$0(AsyncResponseHandler.java:92) ~[sdk-core-2.21.46.jar:na]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniCompose.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:1150) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:510) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.complete(CompletableFuture.java:2147) ~[na:na]
at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.async.AsyncResponseHandler$BaosSubscriber.onComplete(AsyncResponseHandler.java:135) ~[sdk-core-2.21.46.jar:na]
at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.metrics.BytesReadTrackingPublisher$BytesReadTracker.onComplete(BytesReadTrackingPublisher.java:74) ~[sdk-core-2.21.46.jar:na]
at software.amazon.awssdk.http.nio.netty.internal.ResponseHandler$DataCountingPublisher$1.onComplete(ResponseHandler.java:519) ~[netty-nio-client-2.21.46.jar:na]
at software.amazon.awssdk.http.nio.netty.internal.ResponseHandler.runAndLogError(ResponseHandler.java:254) ~[netty-nio-client-2.21.46.jar:na]
at software.amazon.awssdk.http.nio.netty.internal.ResponseHandler.access$600(ResponseHandler.java:77) ~[netty-nio-client-2.21.46.jar:na]
at software.amazon.awssdk.http.nio.netty.internal.ResponseHandler$PublisherAdapter$1.onComplete(ResponseHandler.java:375) ~[netty-nio-client-2.21.46.jar:na]
at software.amazon.awssdk.http.nio.netty.internal.nrs.HandlerPublisher.publishMessage(HandlerPublisher.java:402) ~[netty-nio-client-2.21.46.jar:na]
at software.amazon.awssdk.http.nio.netty.internal.nrs.HandlerPublisher.flushBuffer(HandlerPublisher.java:338) ~[netty-nio-client-2.21.46.jar:na]
at software.amazon.awssdk.http.nio.netty.internal.nrs.HandlerPublisher.receivedDemand(HandlerPublisher.java:291) ~[netty-nio-client-2.21.46.jar:na]
at software.amazon.awssdk.http.nio.netty.internal.nrs.HandlerPublisher.access$200(HandlerPublisher.java:61) ~[netty-nio-client-2.21.46.jar:na]
at software.amazon.awssdk.http.nio.netty.internal.nrs.HandlerPublisher$ChannelSubscription$1.run(HandlerPublisher.java:495) ~[netty-nio-client-2.21.46.jar:na]
at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.runTask(AbstractEventExecutor.java:173) ~[netty-common-4.1.111.Final.jar:4.1.111.Final]
at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:166) ~[netty-common-4.1.111.Final.jar:4.1.111.Final]
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:469) ~[netty-common-4.1.111.Final.jar:4.1.111.Final]
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:566) ~[netty-transport-4.1.111.Final.jar:4.1.111.Final]
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:994) ~[netty-common-4.1.111.Final.jar:4.1.111.Final]
at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[netty-common-4.1.111.Final.jar:4.1.111.Final]
... 1 common frames omitted
Tried to update Async SQS build step but no luck.  Would like to see the application able to poll SQS queue and process the requests.
===== additional information
I could see from AWS documentation (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/APIReference/CommonErrors.html) that potential reason for 403 error is
InvalidClientTokenId
The X.509 certificate or AWS access key ID provided does not exist in our records.
Access Key ID/secret key are validated and look good.
In the legacy code, below line exists and not upgraded but commented instead.
Couldn't find the documentation/details on how to upgrade the below two lines within the method public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http)
.addFilterBefore(keycloakAuthenticationProcessingFilter(), X509AuthenticationFilter.class)
.addFilterBefore(keycloakPreAuthActionsFilter(), LogoutFilter.class)
Any pointers/details would be much appreciated.

Are you using AWS Keys to authenticate?

Also - are you using both , AWS SDK 2.x and Spring Cloud. That does not sound like best practice. I would recomend using just AWS SDK Java V2 API.

Yes, AWS Keys are used to authenticate and I've validated them for correctness.  Queue initiation is successful.

I'm working on a legacy code and primarily to upgrade from Java 8 to 17 in the next release.  However, thanks for your suggestion.  We will see how to consolidate in a future release.

If you are using Spring Cloud AWS please check how you are configuration credentials since this is credentials issue. You can find details about autoconfiguration of credentials.
If you are not using Spring Cloud AWS you can check simplicity of SQS integration here in our samples and read documentation
Also, if you are using Spring Boot version 3.1.x or 3.0.x use Spring Cloud AWS 3.1.x and for Spring Boot 3.2+ please upgrade to 3.2.x

Thank you for your time and response.  yes, it seems to be pertaining to credentials/authentication.  I've added more details below 'additional information' line in the original request.  Any pointers/details would be much appreciated.

Thank you.  Yes, I noticed that access key associated with the user is not included in the AWS SQS permission/policy.   Adding it to the policy has resolved the issue.  Thanks again!
